# Unable to get children of IContent

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

I'm trying to get the `Children` of an `Icontent` object.

```
IContent filialsParent = cs.GetById(filialParrentId);

if (filialsParent != null)
{
    IContentService contentService = Umbraco.Core.Composing.Current.Services.ContentService;
    bool hasChildren = contentService.HasChildren(filialsParent.Id);
    long totalChildren;

    IEnumerable<IContent> children = contentService.GetPagedChildren(filialsParent.Id, 1, 100, out totalChildren);

    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        context.WriteLine(string.Format("child: {0}", child.Name));
    }

    context.WriteLine(string.Format("Children found:({0}) in: {1}", children.Count(), filialParrentId));

}
```

If I debug the code, I get the following.

My `long totalChildren` will be 1 after the line `contentService.GetPagedChildren(filialsParent.Id, 1, 100, out totalChildren);` runs.

My `IEnumerable<IContent> children` is null, and for that reason (of course) is my `children.Count()` 0

Sadly `filialsParent` does not contain the function `.children()` as I hoped it would.

Is there a way to get the Children of my `filialsParent`, and yes it does have children that are published.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dit got the exact same problem. For testing purposes I removed everything Only bare essentials.

==> umbraco 8.0.2

Make sure you got a parent and a few childeren attached

```
// For testing purposes hardcode your parent Id
var contentId = [ID];

// SET for returning total records
long totalChildren;

// int id ==> You even could hardcode your first param (contentID in here)
// long pageIndex ==> SET your index to 0 ==> first indexpage starts at 0 and not 1 ==> if you set this to 1 and the Pagesize = 100  and you have only 99 childeren you wil wil get null because we are requesting the second page
// int pageSize ==> We need max 10 childeren
// out long totalChildren 
// IQuery<IContent> filter = null ==> not used 
// Ordering ordering = null ==> not used
IEnumerable<IContent> children = Services.ContentService.GetPagedChildren(contentId, 0, 10, out totalChildren);
```